How to make looping to be the fastest in R?
I am doing a simulation study. I am taking Exponential Distribution as an example.
A short introduction here... given that F(x) = 1 - e^(-λx), so x = (-ln[1-F(x)])/(λ). In R, I will write it as x = (-log(1-p))/(lambda) where F(x) is p. Same goes to its log-likelihood, L_X = n_x*log(lambda) - lambda*sum(x)
Because I am planning to run the iterations up to 1 million times, I am seeking for a faster version.
(The loop approach takes almost 10 hours, while the parallel version takes around 3.4 hours. I definitely need to improve the speed and efficiency.)
My objective is to collect all the value of "simulated lambda"
(1) Base Loop:
iterations <- 100
lambda = 35 #par[1]

simulation <- function(i) {
  
  p <- runif(1000, 0, 1)
  x <- (-log(1-p))/(lambda)
  n_x <- length(x)
  
  loglikelihood = function(par, x, y){
    return( -(n_x*log(par[1]) - par[1]*sum(x)))
  }
  
  result <- optim(c(10), fn = loglikelihood, x = x , method = "Brent",
                  lower = 0, upper = 100)
  
  return(result$par)
}

results_list <- lapply(1:iterations, simulation)                          
results <- do.call(rbind, results_list)
colnames(results) <- c("lambda_sim")
results

(2) Parallel Approach:
future::plan(future::multisession, workers = parallelly::availableCores() - 1)

iterations <- 100
lambda = 35 #par[1]

simulation <- function(i) {
  
  p <- runif(1000, 0, 1)
  x <- (-log(1-p))/(lambda)
  n_x <- length(x)
  
  loglikelihood = function(par, x, y){
    return( -(n_x*log(par[1]) - par[1]*sum(x)))
  }
  
  result <- optim(c(10), fn = loglikelihood, x = x , method = "Brent",
                  lower = 0, upper = 100)   

  return(result$par)
}

results_list <- future.apply::future_lapply(1:iterations, simulation, future.seed = TRUE) 
results <- do.call(rbind, results_list)
colnames(results) <- c("lambda_sim")

future::plan(future::sequential)

Not sure clusterApply() is the current fastest in R? Anyway I would like to ask how can we determine the initial value when using optim() in a new post...

In base R, we can do a lot here. First of all, it might be good to describe your approach and specify the desired result. Second, your current attempt issues There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50). I do not think parallel or future.apply is (really) needed here. Out of interest, why do you use logb()?

Hi @Friede , my desired result is to make the looping faster... because the improved version is faster than the original one. So I am wondering how to improve the code further more...

Therefore, please explain what you desire to achieve with your code, which does not run warning-free. Why not optimize() instead of optim()?

@Friede , thank you for editing my post into more readable, appreciate it. I am sorry if I didn't answer your question, the reason I use optim() because I only approach optim() ... I will look into optimize() later. But is optimize more powerful?
Anyway, I use logb() because there is a Natural logarithm in the equation...  :)

Unfortunately , that does not make sense to me. You haven't found the distinction between log() and logb(). As you use the latter explicitly, I thought there is a reason for doing so.

You should describe in words: What is your code doing? What do you want to achieve? What is the objective in optimization? I went through your optimization problem but had no clue what the problem it is. Are you using uniform random variable to generate some random sample of a certain distribution? Just my guess. You should tell the goal first and then other can continue.

@Friede . To be honest I never know the difference between log() and logb() until you tell me. All the while I thought logb() means log with base "e", while log() means log with base 10. Now I only know both are the same. sigh :( ...

@ThomasIsCoding I see. I have updated my objective in the question. My objective is to collect the "simulated alpha" and then calculate the mean, and standard deviation... did I answer the question? Thanks for the patience...

You'd better double check the objective function f for optimization. If it is monotone and unbounded, then it makes no sense to optimize.

The random variable is p, not alpha!

If possible, you could show the formula or rationale that your code relies to. My understanding is that, your "optimization" is not a valid or properly formulated optimization problem.

@ThomasIsCoding sure. I will ask in a new post instead... my bad. Initially I thought simply put a function f will do but yeah. I will open a new question soon...thanks for the tips..

You can edit your question (no need to create a new one) and then we vote to reopen it

@ThomasIsCoding Thanks for your patience. I have edited my question with a Exponential Distribution included, hope it makes more sense now. But this lead to a new question -- instead of guessing the initial value in optim() , how can we give a "proper" initial value?

@Friede I have edited my question, hopefully it would be better as I included Exponential Distribution into. Thanks for your guidance and I take it positively :)

Rather than simulating massive iterations then taking the average, you can equivalently expand the sample size by p <- runif(1000*iterations, 0, 1) and run optim once only. The speed bottleneck is optim, so multiple simulations enlarges the slowness.

@Friede , I am sorry, I got the Error in apply(P, function(j) -f(lambda, j)) :    argument "FUN" is missing, with no default when trying your suggestions, do you mean apply(P, 2, function(j) -f(j, lambda)) ?

@ThomasIsCoding I see, thanks... can you help to vote to open back the questions? Need help...

@Gambit yes, I have voted to reopen it, but need more people to join the voting

Thank you very much. Appreciate your help... @Friede need your help as well......

For i=100; n=1000; lambda=35, are you looking for p = runif(n*i); x = - log(1L-p)/lambda; nx = i*n; f = \(x, lambda) lambda*sum(x)-nx*log(lambda); optim(10L, fn = f, x = x, method = "Brent", lower = 0, upper = 100)$par?

This does not really matter: the result is close to your choice of lambda, i.e. you might want to use lambda as initial value in optim.

For this particular example, there is a closed-form solution: differentiating with respect to par[1] and solving for par[1] gives n_x/sum(x) for the value that minimizes the function.  But presumably you want to be able to generalize ... ??

Also: the reason to use optimize() is that for one-dimensional problems, it's likely faster and more robust, and guaranteed -- you don't have to give an initial value, just lower and upper bounds.

I do not think things became more clear. Overall goal? Exact formula/design? No close solution? How many parameters? Why so many replications  (iterations)? Why "Brent"? ...

@Friede, they're presumably using "Brent" because it's best for 1D optimization. (You're right that it would help to know if (1) they only want to do this for exponential distribution (or other distributions with a closed-form answer), (2) they only want to do this for 1-parameter distributions (or at least for distributions with only one unknown/estimated parameter) [parallelization will definitely help, but only after making the inner part as efficient as possible]

Since you already know the distribution, i.e., exponential distribution, you can directly obtain a closed-form estimate of lambda with respect to given samples x.
f <- \(iter, n = 1e3) {
  replicate(iter, {
    p <- runif(n)
    x <- (-log(1 - p)) / (lambda)
    1 / mean(x)
  })
}

and you can see that
> system.time(f(1e6))
   user  system elapsed 
  52.22    0.38   52.85

and
> head(f(1e6))
[1] 34.24897 36.12484 34.06128 36.66326 35.39527 35.24301


Unfortunately, I suspect "I am taking Exponential Distribution as an example."  is nothing than an unlucky choice.

Thank you, @ThomasIsCoding. I not only learned a new way to code, but also gained a deep appreciation for your admirable patience in this educational environment. I truly appreciate it.
